# second order coupled odes solving for double spring dampener system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a spring dampener system and have managed to get the coupled odes:
$$\begin{pmatrix}m_1&0\\0&m_2\end{pmatrix}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}c_1+c_2&-c_2\\-c_2&c_2\end{pmatrix}\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}k_1+k_2&-k_2\\-k_2&k_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=0$$

In terms of constants and initial conditions:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}(t=0)=\begin{pmatrix}5\\10\end{pmatrix},\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}(t=0)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
I would like to try and keep the constants open if possible to model different situations but if they are needed for a method then I can provide a sample for them. I would just like some advice and a starter on how to begin solving a system like this so that I can work it out for myself. Thanks :)

---

As suggested by changing this into a system of four equations I get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\\z_3\\z_4\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\-\frac{k_1+k_2}{m_1}&-\frac{c_1+c_2}{m_1}&\frac{k_2}{m_1}&\frac{c_2}{m_1}\\0&0&0&1\\\frac{k_2}{m_2}&-\frac{k_2}{m_2}&\frac{c_2}{m_2}&-\frac{c_2}{m_2}\end{pmatrix}$$
subject to:
$$\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2\\z_3\\z_4\end{pmatrix}(0)=\begin{pmatrix}5\\10\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you write as a system of four first order equations and then use eigenvalues/eigenvectors to solve it?

Comment: I will try writing that out and share what I get, thank you

Comment: Can you now go about finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I used Mathematica and found them, but they are rather ugly.Are there any parameters in your system that are fixed - that would certainly help?

Comment: Not really although c1=c2 and k1=k2 is a prominent case so if that helps I'm happy just getting a solution to that